# How Do I Integrate Paypal, Gravity Forms And Wishlist?

Tags: paypal, integration

First off, I'm by no means a programmer so this might be a very simple issue but I'm about to pull my hair out soon.

So, I have a site where I'm selling a book + access to a membership through Wishlist Member. It sells for $99 and now I want to give them a $9 trial for 30 days and then bill them the remaining $90 over 2 installments of $45 each with a month apart.

Now, integrating Wishlist with PP is easy to setup when I'm only sending people straight to PayPal.

It basically only requires 3 steps besides activating IPN and pasting in the PDT.

1. Add the item/subscription ID of my Wishlist Membership Level to the PayPal button I'm creating.
2. Make sure the thank you page URL after purchase is:

   site.com/members/index.php/register/AOKmfa
3. Paste the code below in the "Add advanced variables" field:

   rm=2 
   bn=WishListProducts_SP
   notify_url=site.com/members/index.php/register/AOKmfa
   return=site.com/members/index.php/register/AOKmfa

Now I'm looking to increase the sign up rate so I am creating my own order page with Gravity Forms Paypal-Add on.

In there you have an option to set the thank you page, so in my case I would add "site.com/members/index.php/register/AOKmfa" and then I can also tick a box that says:

"Pass Field Data Via Query String" where I'm apparently suppose to paste in the code:

```
rm=2 
bn=WishListProducts_SP
notify_url=site.com/members/index.php/register/AOKmfa
return=site.com/members/index.php/register/AOKmfa
```

But, my question is... how can I get this subscription ID involved?!

**After speaking to Gravity Form support they said:**

To pass additional info to PayPal you can use gform_paypal_query filter. You adapt this code to suit your needs.

```
add_filter('gform_paypal_query', 'add_more_information', 10, 3); 
function add_more_information($query_string, $form, $entry) {
    // break the query string into an array
    // after removing the initial '&' character
    parse_str(ltrim($query_string, '&'), $query);

    // add information to query string.  These currently exist
    /* 
    [METHOD]
    [VERSION]
    [PWD]
    [USER]
    [SIGNATURE]
    [BUTTONSOURCE]
    [CREDITCARDTYPE]
    [ACCT]
    [EXPDATE]
    [CVV2]
    [STREET]
    [STREET2]
    [CITY]
    [STATE]
    [ZIP]
    [COUNTRYCODE]
    [CURRENCYCODE]
    [FIRSTNAME]
    [LASTNAME]
    [EMAIL]
    [DESC]
    [L_NAME0]
    [L_DESC0]
    [L_AMT0]
    [L_NUMBER0]
    [L_QTY0]
    [PAYMENTACTION]
    [IPADDRESS]
    [RETURNFMFDETAILS]
    [AMT]
    [NOTIFYURL]
    */
    // change SHIPTONAME to whatever query string parameter you want to set
    // and change the inputs here to whatever field holds your item title.
    $query['L_DESC0'] = rgpost("input_6_13");

    // put it all back together again
    $query_string = '&' . http_build_query($query);
    return $query_string;
}
```

So my question is, how can I adapt that code to actually get this integration to work? They are clearly not interested in pinpointing exactly how I would go about doing it so maybe one of you can?

Do I only need to adapt the code so it somehow adds in that subscription ID? (If so, how?) Or do I also need to add in the redirect url and the advanced variable field?

I truly appreciate any kind of help you can give me and if this should be posted elsewhere please let me know.

Thanks,

Tony